# In SpringMVC, Retain full Model object even if some fields aren't bound

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

We have a situation where our Model object (a Java POJO) contains some extra fields that aren't bound on the current Form. In other words, the Form could contain 3 text fields, which the Model has, but the Model also has a lot of other stuff.

When I submit my form, I lose everything that isn't bound. So my Model object loses all the info except the 3 input fields that are bound.

Is there a way to carry forward or retain my full Model object between form submissions, or not lose that unbound data?

Comment: you should use <form:hidden path="yourAttribute" /> in the form.

Comment: But I have complex objects stored in my Model. A Hidden Field can't point to complex objects, only strings.

Comment: Then, after you submit form, connect database again  and get extra fields with unique id.  seperate your pojo into two pojos with unique id.

Comment: Store them in the session? request.getSession().addAttribute..

Comment: Serialize the complex object e.g. to JSON and send in a hidden param to form

Comment: That is what `@SessionAttributes` are made for.

Comment: In modern development Session usage should be minimized. Session vars are unreliable and can get corrupted between requests, you never know who accesses them and how.